# lambda expression is a free variable that gets bound at runtime, not definition time?

Tags: python, lambda

I am learning python program syntax and do not have too much program experience. I have trouble to understand the statement that show in the title. I find a relevant piece of code to explain the statement, but I still can not understand it clearly.
Can anyone illustrate the statement according to the code ,please? Also briefly explain the difference between runtime and definition time? I try to google the the terminology of definition time, but I do not get a comprehend answer.

```
>>> x = 10
>>> a = lambda y: x + y 
>>> x = 20
>>> b = lambda y: x + y 
>>>
when I call the function a with argument 10, I get a unexpected result.
>>> a(10) 
30              # why the result is not 20,30 respectively ?
>>> b(10) 
30              
>>>
```

Comment: I try to google what is definition time and I can not get my expected answer? Can anyone explain to me in a pain English? Thanks

Comment: The difference is just caused because you have called your function after overriding your initial value of x.That is x was 20 when you called a(10).

Answer (score 4):

Think of it this way. When a function is invoked, if a variable used in it, is not defined in it, then it will go to the previous level and try to find the variable there. If it is not there, then go up and the searching continues till the top level is reached.

In your case, when you do

```
>>> a(10)
```

the function `a` is executed and it is not able to find `x` in it, and it goes up one level and finds `x` there. The current value of `x` is 20. That is why you are getting `30`.

Check out the following examples, they might help you understand this better.

```
>>> x = 10
>>> a = lambda y: x + y 
>>> a(10)
20
>>> x = 20
>>> a(10)
30
```

Also this

```
>>> a = lambda y: z + y 
>>> a(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'z' is not defined
>>> z = 20
>>> a(10)
30
```

In the second example, `z` is not even defined when `a` is defined. But when you invoke `a` the second time, `z` is defined in the previous namespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
b = lambda y: x + y
```

is effectively the same as

```
def b(y):
    return x + y
```

When `x` is not found in the local namespace (i.e., within the function or its arguments), Python looks for it in the "parent" namespace, where it is equal to 20 at the time the functions are called.

Comment: Do you mean python looks for the parent namespace right AFTER the function is called ?

Comment: Python looks *in* the parent namespace *at the time* the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have later on defined x as being equal to 20.
So the later value of x is 20,
So when you do

```
>>> a = lambda y: x + y
```

then `x` is `20`, because you have called the print function after declaring the new value of `x`.

If you want to see your answer as `20`, you should call `a(20)`, just after

```
>>> x = 10
>>> a = lambda y: x + y 
>>> a(10)
20
```

Answer (score 0):

The body of a function, whether defined with `lambda` or `def`, does not bind vaariables until the function is run (it does bind scope, so running it elsewhere doesn't pick up someone else's `x`).

If you want definition time binding, you can fake it a bit with default arguments:

```
a = lambda y, x=x: x + y
```

So when called with one argument, it uses the definition time value of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

When you defined your `a = lambda y: x+y`, `x` at definition time of `a` was equal to `10`, but after you re-defined `x` to be `20`, at running time of `a(x)`, it will take the last value defined to `x` (at run time which is `20` and not `10`), which will gives `a(10) = x + y = 20 + 10 = 30`